# .bin file synced from Perforce is getting corrupted

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have checked in .bin file of size 778,379kb into Perforce.

When I sync the file I got a file of size 778,368kb.

What caused this ? Why the file is getting corrupted ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Does Perforce know it's a binary file? Run `p4 fstat .bin`; you must see `headType binary` in the output.

Comment: Its my mistake I checked-in the binary files as file type text. P4 edit with file type as binary solved the issue.